# Создание видео из фото и аудио

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg

У меня есть .png изображение и .mp3 файл, необходимо создать видео, длина которого будет равна длине .mp3 файла. Само видео состоит из одного кадра, который постоянно повторяется, кадр это изображение .png. (На выходе должен получится .mp4)

Какие библиотеки/готовые решения лучше использовать для этого? Находил вариант использования FFMPeG + OpenCV, но довольно таки сложный, возможно, есть что-то более простое.

Answer (score 0):

Из текста вопроса не понятно: это нужно таким образом организовать вызов утилиты ffmpeg или программно, используя FFmpeg API (libavformat, codec и так далее)? (а в комментарии неудобно вставлять ссылки :))

Для первого варианта, для картинки просто задайте параметр [`-loop 1`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Advanced-options) и `-shortest` (расположение параметров - важно!) или воспользуйтесь фильтром [loop](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#loop).

Пример:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i file.mp3 -shortest out.mkv
```

Возможно понадобится параметр `-pix_fmt yuv420p` после `-shortest`.

У x264 (`-c:v libx264`) есть ещё опция тюнинга - `stillimage` (`-tune stillimage`), позволяющая оптимизировать процесс сжатия для стоячего кадра.

При программной реализации тоже проблем не вижу. Прикидываете какой FPS вам нужен, читаете и декодируется PNG файл в `AVFrame` после чего с нужным периодом кодируете его кодеком и пишете получившийся `AVPacket` в муксер. Не забывайте правильно считать PTS для пакета. Каждый раз кодировать нужно, что бы кодек набрал статистику и смог экономить на промежуточных кадрах.

Собственно фильтр loop можно использовать и в программной реализации тоже.

Дерзайте!